# Redirect dynamic urls from id/article to /article

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would really appreciate your help.

I have a website: http// mywebsite.tdl
I have a subdirectory: http:// mywebsite.tdl /articles
I have articles vieweable in 2 ways: http:// mywebsite.tdl /articles/myarticle OR
http:// mywebsite.tdl /articles/ID/myarticle

ID is a number of course

I would like to know how can I redirect http:// mywebsite.tdl /articles/ID/myarticle
to http:// mywebsite.tdl /articles/myarticle so I can finally get rid of duplicate content.

ALSO, If there is a solution to this, I would like to exclude (if needed) articles like this: http:// mywebsite.tdl /articles/5-ways-to-blablabla

because I AM THINKING the number "5" in this case, may be confused as the ID causing it to be redirected to http:// mywebsite.tdl /articles/-ways-to-blablabla = 404 error.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/DocumentRoot/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(articles)/\d+/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply anubhava. "articles" is not actually a real subfolder but it is automatically generated. How should I change your code then? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will never stop thanking you!

Comment: just as a note, .htaccess usage adds performance penalties, since it has to access the file each time a resource in that directory or any subdirectory is accessed. if you're using a framework, you might want to leverage it's internal routing mechanism, or process the request at the application level rather than altering the server's configuration.

Comment: @Radu: First of all that comment is not related to the question here. Also is there no performance issue with using code level routing rather than doing it via .htaccess?

Comment: it was just a note related to your answer ;) and no, I don't think processing the request at the code level adds performance penalties unless is done wrong. every processing routine is a resources consumer. there are also consequences from the application's architecture point of view when you use .htaccess config files.

Comment: **I don't think processing the request at the code level adds performance penalties**: Then you need to do a bit of reading to understand performance comparison between routing using .htaccess vs routing using custom code.

Comment: Thank you for your pracisation. I am not able with my knowledge to change the code and I am using a CMS called JOOMLA and a component called K2. I googled a lot but no result found so I though the solution was using a redirect. My website is not very fast and I know it is related to javascript (I tried disabling it and my website is a rocket) but I think it is not related to the question.